# Modifying Word Document Properties

Tags: php

I want to send a Microsoft Word document. But before I send I want to modify its properties like (document title, subject, author, team, manager, company etc.) before sending using PHP.

I cannot use COM as i just learned that the server where this script will run does not have ms office nor am i allowed to install it...so pls give me some other solution.

Thanks

Comment: anyone taught you title and body?

Comment: What Version of Word document? The new XML-based format, or the old proprietary .doc?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper be easy..
@shazia try to let the title be as brief and to the point as possible. Elaborate more in body

Comment: Are you on a Windows server with Word installed?

Comment: @Amjad @shazia sorry, it's just that there are too many poor quality posts lately.

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is working with [Component Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) in PHP, here is another [tutorial](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch15_03.htm)
**EDIT**
Sample code to open new MS Word document:

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("something went wrong!!");
//open new word document
$word->Documents->Add();
//type text into the document
$word->Selection->TypeText("this is some sample text in the document");
//save document
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("newWordDocument.doc");
//close word
$word->Quit();
//free object resources
$word->Release();
$word = null;
```

Comment: Only on Windows though, and Word needs to be installed. Still, it is indeed the best option

Comment: i cannot find COM API can u paste link

Comment: Thanks but i tried the code and a lot of others but nothing happens...as soon as  i try to open word document it just keeps processing..is there any changes i need to make in php.ini or somewhere else. It doesn't give me error neither does it time out.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to open COM but it just keeps processing .

> $word = new COM("word.application") or
>   die("Unable to instantiate application
>   object");
>
> $DocumentPath=$newname; // open up anempty document
>
> $wordDocument = $word->Documents->Open($DocumentPath);
>   >
>
> // clean up
>
> $wordDocument = null;
>   $word->Quit();
>
> $word = null;

if I add this line then it keeps processing.. if i commnet it i cannot open the document...am i doing something wrong

> $word->Documents->Open($DocumentPath);

Comment: I just edited my post above and included a code snippet to create a new document and save it. Dont forget to accept answer..

Answer (score 0):

since the problem is with the server environment - I would suggest using OpenOffice and a component [phpdocwriter](http://phpdocwriter.sourceforge.net/). It is capable of loading Microsoft Office document and manipulate their information.

Hope this helps!